# Django backend disconnects after closing Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a backend in Django that has functions that are communicated using gets and posts that are periodically ran using chrome.alarms. I create my alarms in a componentDidMount and then fire them. When I have the Chrome Extension open these functions are run correctly and periodically. However, the moment I click the screen and the Chrome Extension popup goes away these functions stop running. The only thing I base upon the Chrome Extension popup is gathering the tab url which is shown in the sendThr function using a post request and chrome.tabs.query. Why does everything else seem to also be dependent on the Chrome Extension popup being open?

```
class Thresholds extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        console.log("setting state properties");
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isRoadblock: false,
            previousRoadblock: false,
            isCompletion: false,
            ran: false,
            wordpageCount: "",
            tabUrl: "",
            // keywords: "",
            open: false,
            title: "",
            extensionID: "ocpjnbkledofcgolfcpkebgkpmfjgjgj",
            data: ""
        };
    }

    showRoadblockNotifications() {
        console.log(this.n.supported())
        if (this.n.supported()); 
        this.n.show();
    }

    showCompNotifications() {
        console.log(this.a.supported())
        if (this.a.supported());
        this.a.show();
    }

    handleRoadClick(event) {
        this.n.close(event.target.tag);
    }

    handleCompClick(event) {
        this.a.close(event.target.tag);
    }    

    sendThr = (() => {
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ml/thr', 
        { wordpageCount: this.state.wordpageCount
        }).then((res) => {                                   
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
            chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
             // since only one tab should be active and in the current window at once
             // the return variable should only have one entry
             var activeTab = tabs[0];
             activeTab = activeTab.url
             axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ml/link', 
             { activeTab: activeTab
             }).then((res) => {                                   
                 console.log("ml/link: ", res.data);
                 console.log("activeTab: ", activeTab)
             })
         })
        
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'We expect you to take ' + (res.data).toFixed(2) + ' minutes',
                text: "",
                icon: 'OK',
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'OK',
             })
         })
    })

    componentDidMount() {
        function sendML() {   
            // console.log("send ml")
            axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/ml/rbml").then(res => {
                console.log("ml/rbml: ", res.data);
            })
        }
    
        function textComps() {   
            // console.log("textcomps")
            axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/textcomps").then(res => {
                console.log("api/textcomps: ", res.data);
            })
        }
    
        function checkRoadblock() { 
            axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/roadblock").then(res => {
                // console.log("check roadblock")
                console.log("api/roadblock: ", res.data);
                if (res.data) {
                    this.state.isRoadblock = true;
                    console.log("previous roadblock: ", this.state.previousRoadblock);
                    console.log("current roadblock: ", this.state.isRoadblock);
                    if (this.state.previousRoadblock == false) {
                        if (this.state.isRoadblock == true) {
                            console.log("roadblock notifs");
                            var tip = tips[Math.floor(Math.random()*tips.length)];
                            alert("You've approached a roadblock!" + "\n" + tip);
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }).catch (
                function (error) {
                    console.log('Show error notification! ' + error)
                    return Promise.reject(error)
                }
            )
            this.state.previousRoadblock = this.state.isRoadblock
            this.state.isRoadblock = false;
        }
    
        function checkCompletion() {
            axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/completion").then(res => {
                // console.log("check completion")
                console.log("api/completion: ", res.data);
                if (res.data) {
                    this.state.isCompletion = true;
                    if (this.state.isCompletion) {
                            console.log("completion notifs");
                            alert("You've completed your goal! Congratulations on completing your assignment!");
                    }
                    this.state.isCompletion = false;
                }
            }).catch (
                function (error) {
                    console.log('Show error notification! ' + error)
                    return Promise.reject(error)
                }
            )
        }   

        // Creates an alarm that start 30 seconds after creation and pings every minute
        chrome.alarms.create("roadblockAlarm", {periodInMinutes: .1});
              
        // Create an alarm that pings every 5 minutes
        chrome.alarms.create("sendMLAlarm", {periodInMinutes: 5}); 

        chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(a => {
            console.log("Alarm fired");
            console.log(a);
            if (a.name == "roadblockAlarm") {
                textComps()
                checkRoadblock()
                checkCompletion()
            } else if (a == "sendMLAlarm") {
                sendML()
            } else {
                console.log("Incompatible alarm type")
            }
        });
    }

    //     axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/ml/keywords", 
    //     { keywords: this.state.keywords}
    //     ).then((res) => {    
    //         // var keywords = String(this.state.keyword1, this.state.keyword2, this.state.keyword3);
    //         // var strToken = keywords.split(", ");
    //         // console.log(strToken);                              
    //         // console.log(res);
    //         console.log("ml/keywords: ", res.data);
    //     })
   
    handleCallbackOne = (childData) =>{
        // console.log(childData);
        // this.setState({LineSpace: childData})
        this.setState({ ...this.state , wordpageCount: childData });
    }

    // handleCallbackTwo = (childData) =>{
    //     // console.log(childData);
    //     // this.setState({LineSpace: childData})
    //     this.setState({ ...this.state , keywords: childData });
    // }

    handleButtonClick() {
        if(this.state.ignore) {
        return;
        }

        const now = Date.now();
        const title = 'React-Web-Notification' + now;
        const body = 'Hello' + new Date();
        const tag = now;
        const options = {
            tag: tag,
            body: body,
            // icon: icon,
            lang: 'en',
            dir: 'ltr',
            // sound: './sound.mp3'  // no browsers supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification/sound#Browser_compatibility
        }
        this.setState({
            title: title,
            options: options
        });
    }
    
    handleButtonClick2() {
        this.props.swRegistration.getNotifications({}).then(function(notifications) {
        console.log(notifications);
        });
    }
        
    // const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='thresholdsList'>
                <ReactNotifications
                    onRef={ref => (this.n = ref)} 
                        title="You have approached a roadblock!"
                        body="You have approached a roadblock!"
                        tag="roadblock"
                        timeout="2000"
                    onClick={event => this.handleRoadClick(event)}
                />
                <ReactNotifications
                    onRef={ref => (this.a = ref)} 
                        title="You have completed your goal!"
                        body="You have completed your goal!"
                        tag="completion"
                        timeout="2000"
                    onClick={event => this.handleCompClick(event)}
                />
              <div id="thresholdsList">
                  <WordPageCount parentCallback = {this.handleCallbackOne} />
                  {/* <Keywords parentCallback = {this.handleCallbackTwo}></Keywords> */}
                  <button id="btn" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.sendThr}>Submit</button>
              </div>
          </div>)
    }
}

export default Thresholds
```

Comment: The popup runs only when shown. To listen to messages when it's closed you need to do it in a separate hidden background script (service worker), which is not a part of the popup.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you, the code I included in my post is my background script. Is it problematic to have it in reactJS?

Comment: The background script runs in a separate hidden context specified in `background` section of manifest.json. Don't load it anywhere else. Use separate scripts for the popup and for the background script. You can use messaging to communicate between them.